Wireless charging not charging to 100% consistently
My iphone XMAX is not charging to 100% when on its (non apple) wireless charger. It used to work consistently, now it only reaches 60-70%. What could be the reason behind it? Charging on cable still works. Sometimes it goes up to 100% on wireless, sometimes it stays below no matter how long.
I also tried other wireless chargers and power outlets.

It may overheat. If you look into battery settings after charge has seemingly stopped, it may say something like "iPhone stopped charging due to overheating"

then why doesnt it continue after cooling down a bit?

It may not be possible for it to cool down unless you don't use it at all. Probably you're running something like mobile hotspot which heats your device. For example, if I'm using a mobile hotspot on 5G and charging with wire (not wirelessly) on my iPhone 12, then often it never makes it past 80% and always stuck on it until I disable hotspot. Worth nothing that wireless charging generally charges slower and exerts more heat as opposed to wired charging.
